# Return end of number

Tags: bash, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I can return the beginning of a hex number like this

```
$ printf %x $(( 0x07d00050 >> 16 ))
7d0
```

However in this case I would like to return the end `0050`. I tried this with no luck

```
$ printf %x $(( 0x07d00050 << 16 ))
7d000500000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mask bits, you should use the binary AND operator, which is `&`:

```
printf %04x $(( 0x07d0050 & 0xffff ))
```

Comment: You use binary AND in order to mask bits.

Comment: Finally, is my way the best for returning the beginning?

Comment: Sure. They're not beginning and end, they're high-order bits and low-order bits. Just remember that these are binary numbers, and it should be clear how to do what you want with them.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
printf "%04x" $(( 0x07d00050 & 0xFFFF))
```